# Java Custom 3D Rotation doesn't look right

Tags: java, swing, 3d, rotation

## Java 3D Renderering

#### Context

Currently, I am working on a small 3D renderer. I am using Java.

#### The Problem

When I am rotating shapes, I noticed that the rotation is completely incorrect

(video on bottom)

#### What have I done?

I have:

- Searched Stack Overflow
- Printed out debug info
- Redid rotation

None of these has worked.

## Code

### TVector

```java
public class TVector {
  public float x, y, z;
  public TVector ogPos;
  
  public TVector(float _x, float _y, float _z) {
    this.x = _x;
    this.y = _y;
    this.z = _z;

    this.ogPos = new TVector(this.x, this.y, this.z, true);
  }

  private TVector(float _x, float _y, float _z, boolean _throw) {
    this.x = _x;
    this.y = _y;
    this.z = _z;
  }
  
  public TVector convertToOrthographic() {
    return new TVector(this.x, this.y, 0);
  }
}
```

### Mesh

```java
public class Mesh {
  public Triangle[] tris;
  public TVector rot = new TVector(0, 0, 0);

  public void RotateX(float theta) {
    this.rot.x += theta;
    this.rot.x %= 360;
    double cos = Math.cos(this.rot.x);
    double sin = Math.sin(this.rot.x);
    for (Triangle t : this.tris) {
      for (TVector p : t.points) {
        
        double[][] rotMatrix = new double[][] {
          new double[] {
            1, 0, 0
          },
          new double[] {
            0, cos, -sin
          },
          new double[] {
            0, sin, cos
          }
        };

        double[][] posMatrix = new double[][] {
          new double[] {
            p.ogPos.x
          },
          new double[] {
            p.ogPos.y
          },
          new double[] {
            p.ogPos.z
          }
        };

        double[][] finalRes = Utils.multiplyMatrices(rotMatrix, posMatrix);

        p.x = (float) finalRes[0][0];
        p.y = (float) finalRes[1][0];
        p.z = (float) finalRes[2][0];

        System.out.println(p.x);
        System.out.println(p.y);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Plane

```java
public class Plane extends Mesh {
  public Plane(int x, int y, int z, int length) {
    this.tris = new Triangle[] {
      new Triangle(
        new TVector(x, y, z),
        new TVector(x + length, y, z),
        new TVector(x, y + length, z)
      ),
      new Triangle(
        new TVector(x + length, y - length, z),
        new TVector(x + length, y, z),
        new TVector(x, y + length, z)
      )
    };
  }
}
```

###### Note: There is a window rendering this stuff, and rotating the plane.

### Gif:

[image: GIF]

###### I use REPLIT

Thanks in advance!

Rotation is in degrees.

#### EDIT:

Rotation is less buggier now

[image: GIF]

Comment: Also, I am not a new user, I just forgot my account password :(

Comment: I'm going to task the dumb question - is your input angle in degrees or radians?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Degrees

Comment: Ok, check the documentation for `Math.cos`, I think you'll find it wants it's values in radians

Comment: @MadProgrammer Wow..... While it didn't fix the problem, the rotation is a lot better ;) 

It really just makes the plane move up, but I'm assuming that is a small mistake.

I'll check in the morning, when my brain actually works.